# PHP Output correct in terminal but not in browser

Tags: ssh, shell-exec, php-7.2, sshpass

I just started working with shell_exec in php and stuck at this point.
Below is my php script which runs in terminal correctly but not in browser.

```
<?php
  echo shell_exec("ssh -tq root@192.168.31.5 \"whoami\"");
?>
```

And output in terminal is

```
$ php /var/www/html/monitor/ssh.php 
root
```

But in Browser,
[image: Browser Output]

Interesting thing is just **whoami** works like a charm

```
<?php
    echo shell_exec("whoami");
?>
```

[image]

any suggetion is appriciated. Thank you!

EDIT :- USING OB_START() and OB_GET_CONTENT

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  echo shell_exec("ssh -tq root@192.168.31.5 \"whoami\"");
  $out1 = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  var_dump($out1);
?>
```

OUTPUT IN TERMINAL :-

```
php /var/www/html/monitor/ssh.php 
string(6) "root"
```

OUTPUT IN BROWSER (CHROME) :-

```
string(0) ""
```

Comment: Any updates on this? Facing the same issue on windows using Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

That's because in CLI you're executing the script as the user from SSH (`root` in your case) but in browser, the one executing the script is your `WebServer` (apache/nginx). For you to get *root* as output in browser you might want to have a look at `ob_start ob_get_contents ob_flush` functions.

Comment: but i am logging into other computer through ssh as a root user. The problem is when i execute script on the current computer/server it works fine but same command with ssh on other computer/server doesn't works.